# PHP & AJAX | How would I send a AJAX post request to controller using PHP MVC?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I have researched the similar questions out there but they did not help my problem and some of them were not completely in line with MVC design standards. I am stuck on how to send an AJAX post request from my view to my Controller.

Here is my View

```
<button id = "start_search" class = "btn btn-primary">Search</button>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() { 
$("#start_search").click(function(e) {                
e.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: 'https://phoenix.ltda/api/store/phoenix',
   success: function(data){
        var new_data = JSON.stringify(data);
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo CONTROLLER_PATH . 'admin/AdminStore.php' ?>',
        data: {search_data:new_data},
});
   }
});

    
});
});
</script>
```

Here is my Controller:

```php
<?php

namespace Phoenix\Controllers;

use Phoenix\Database\Database;
use Phoenix\Middlewares\Authentication;
use Phoenix\Middlewares\Csrf;
use Phoenix\Time\Time;

class AdminStore extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        
            if(isset($_POST['search_data'])){
                $fp = fopen("myText.txt","wb");
                fwrite($fp,$_POST['search_data']);
                fclose($fp);
            }
        
        $view = new \Phoenix\Views\View('admin/store/store', (array) $this);

        $this->addViewContent('content', $view->run());
    }
}
?>
```

EDIT: The GET request works but the POST request does not work on the controller. For example if we were to change the POST request url to test.php
if would work. (below)

test.php

```php
    <?php
    
    if(isset($_POST['search_data'])){
        $fp = fopen("myText.txt","wb");
        fwrite($fp,$_POST['search_data']);
        fclose($fp);
    }
    
    ?>
```

As you can see I want the data I get from the URL in my ajax request to be sent to my controller as `$_POST['search_data']` but this does not happen. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Have you done any debugging at all? Is the GET request being made? Is it successful? Is the POST request being made? What data is it sending?

Comment: Just trying to think outside the box here. Another option is to fire your original AJAX request, then fire a CURL request from PHP to your 2nd step, and finally return. This way you only need a single AJAX request.

Comment: @miken32 The GET request works and so does the POST on anything but a class controller.

Comment: What's your exact question about this code? Is that POST request not sent? Is there any error message given?

Comment: @NicoHaase There is no error message being given, I dont think the controller receieves the POST request. The POST request sends though.

Comment: Then what have you tried to debug the problem? Like: starting XDebug to see where your request ends?

Comment: @NicoHaase The POST request sends if I use `url: 'test.php'` in my ajax request. So I know that it works. If I try to send it to the controller file `url: 'AdminStore.php'` I dont get any result. If the POST request did send, it would have created a file called `myText.txt`